# Why point "[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping" when packaging(war) the project using maven?

Tags: maven

When packaging the project using maven, the maven-war-plugin:war goal has the following information.

```
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [xxx] in [/Users/zhangna13/Workspace/xxx/xxx/target/xxx-release-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/Users/zhangna13/Workspace/xxx/xxx/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [2230 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /Users/zhangna13/Workspace/xxx/xxx/target/xxx-release-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
```

I find the web.xml in the target directory, but why 2 web.xml files exist?

Comment: Have you called maven via `mvn clean package`?

Comment: Yes. "mvn clean package". These information is within the maven-war-plugin:war goal.

Comment: Do you have a `web.xml` already in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml` ...

Comment: Yes. And I think it should be the only one.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the warning you have to add the unintuitive configuration parameter `<packagingExcludes>` to the configuration of the `maven-war-plugin`. I put it under `<pluginManagement>`:

```
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

Source: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MWAR-248