# maven WEB-INF\web.xml already added, skipping

Tags: java, maven

When I use `mvn clean package -DskipTests` the console shows:

```
WEB-INF\web.xml already added, skipping
```

This does no harm if web.xml does not refer to any parameter in pom. But if you have a path that takes parameters from maven then this would leave the string as it is.

So how does this web.xml copy competition come out? and how to solve it?
console:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building wx-common 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ wx-common ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\FROM WORKSPACE\workspace\wxflow\wx-common\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:copy-resources (copy-resources) @ wx-common ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 8 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ wx-common ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 14 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ wx-common ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 176 source files to D:\FROM WORKSPACE\workspace\wxflow\wx-common\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ wx-common ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\FROM WORKSPACE\workspace\wxflow\wx-common\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ wx-common ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 20 source files to D:\FROM WORKSPACE\workspace\wxflow\wx-common\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ wx-common ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ wx-common ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [wx-common] in [D:\FROM WORKSPACE\workspace\wxflow\wx-common\target\wx-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [D:\FROM WORKSPACE\workspace\wxflow\wx-common\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [267 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: D:\FROM WORKSPACE\workspace\wxflow\wx-common\target\wx-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] WEB-INF\web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

pom profile and build:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <deploy.type>dev</deploy.type>
                <rp.build.warname>wx-common</rp.build.warname>
                <property.path>/wx-common/prod</property.path>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources/${deploy.type}</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>sms.properties</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/dev/*</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/mappers/*</include>
                    <include>*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

Comment: The downvoter: do you mind answering this question when you down vote it?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890316/why-point-info-web-inf-web-xml-already-added-skipping-when-packagingwar-t/41581268#41581268